# After have all the Patches, NotPetya can still run?

Tags: malware, windows, ransomware

NotPetya runs inmediatly after infection or can be there and being executed even do i have all the security patches?

Answer (score 1):

[NotPetya used](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/27/15879480/petrwrap-virus-ukraine-ransomware-attack-europe-wannacry) the [EternalBlue](https://research.checkpoint.com/eternalblue-everything-know/) exploit in Windows’ SMB file-sharing system for spreading. The vulnerability is patched on every current Windows version ([MS17-010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2017/ms17-010)). This only means you can't get infected with this variant – or any other malware using the same exploit – through SMB. The original Petya didn't use EternelBlue, but required the user to grant it administrative privileges.

But this is just trivia; **there's no particular reason to be afraid of a single malware like this**.